# Printing int value in Text widget flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

How do we print the int value in Text widget? I tried using '$num' but it just come out as instance of num.

This is what i tried so far

```
Text(
   '$widget.count'+'. ',
    style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'sansPro',
    fontSize: 15,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: `intValue.toString()`

Comment: Can you provide more info? In all cases, using `"$myInt"` should be able to handle puting int values inside string. Can you add a bit more detail? Perhaps a few more line of code?

Comment: Consider if you want to use string interpolation and the value has in sub-class or widget, you should use `{}` i.e. `'${widget.count}'+'. '`,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your specific case you need to wrap the data with `{}`, So update the code to the following,

```dart
Text(
   '${widget.count}''. ',
    //...
);
```

**And for more details:**

To "print" or "render" a `num` value that is an `int` or a `double` in dart you can use the `.toString()` method on the variable. You can also use "String Interpolation" that is to evaluate a variable or an expression in a `String`.

For Example to create a `Text` widget that renders the a variable X:

```dart
Text(x.toString());
```

And using String Interpolation, you can use:

```dart
Text("$x");
```

If the variable needs to be evaluated as a part of an expression, That is if the vailable is part of an `Object` or you want to apply an operation before evaluating the final value, then the expression needs to be wrapped within `{}`, the code for that would be

```dart
Text("${x * 100}");
```

Comment: @alep if this answer helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer. So we can help others with the same question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Text widget accept only data in a String format so you can get value in a int or double format and while displaying it convert it into String format. Consider a code snippet like a below:

```
intValueCount.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

**it might be helpful for someone.**

*Issue:How to resolve "Invalid constant value." error - Flutter in VS Code*

Let's suppose you want to show int value in Text e.g

> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
>
> class ProductDetail extends StatelessWidget {   final int productId;
>
> const ProductDetail({super.key, required this.productId});
>
> @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
> return Container(
> child: Text("Id is ${productId} for Product Detail will go here"),
> );   } }

So Make sure no add any const before Text or any widget.

Thanks.