# How to use double value inside Text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using the Data table for showing the product lists and monthly revenue. I need to show annual revenue too, but I didn't get annual revenue from JSON. I only get monthly revenue and I need to multiply monthly revenue with 12 to get annual revenue.
Here is my code for the data table

```
DataTable(
            headingRowColor:
            MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Color(0xFF00105C)),
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Product",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
                    color: Colors.white
                ),)),
              // DataColumn(label: Text("Code")),
              DataColumn(label: Text("Revenue(M)",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
                    color: Colors.white
                ),
              )
              ),
              DataColumn(label: Text("Revenue(A)",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto Bold',
                    color: Colors.white
                ),)),
            ],
            rows: snapshot.data.map((e) => DataRow(
              cells: [

                DataCell(Text(e.product.productName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Regular',
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),),),
                // DataCell(Text(e.product.code)),
                DataCell(Text(e.expectedRevenue.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Regular',
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),)),
                DataCell(Text(e.expectedRevenue*12.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto Regular',
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),)),

              ]
            )).toList(),
          ),
```

expectedRevenue is a dynamic data type in JSON.

```
String id;
int leadProductId;
int leadId;
int productId;
dynamic expectedRevenue;
DateTime createdDate;
int createdBy;
int recordStatus;
dynamic lead;
Product product;
```

Here I got an error for the annual revenue data cell

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' of 'other'
```

How to solve this issue?
**How to find the total value of Revenue(M) column data cells?**

Comment: (e.expectedRevenue*12).toString()  give a try

Comment: @Muhtar it's working. Thanks. Can you suggest a solution to find sum of monthly and annual revenue columns?

Comment: @siyascs is my solution not working?

Comment: Isnt it annual revenue? Could not get what you mean? Could you clarify?

Comment: @Muhtar here I have three columns product, monthly revenue, and annual revenue. I list each product and its monthly and annual revenues. suppose I listed five products with their revenues I need to find the total sum of all monthly revenue and annual revenue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing int value in Text widget flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68043275/printing-int-value-in-text-widget-flutter)

Comment: I posted my answer that you mentioned as it worked. You get monthly revenue and try to find monthly revenue. It doesnt make sense now. In terms of which variable do you want to calculate monthly and annual revenue?

Comment: @Muhtar I have two questions. one is how to multiply monthly revenue with 12 to get annual revenue.  you have given the correct solution for this question. My second question is how to find some of a column in the data table widget if the data cells of this column are numbers in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should replace your code with ;

```
(e.expectedRevenue*12).toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
double.parse(e.expectedRevenue)*12
```

Answer (score 1):

you set the "expectedRevenue" as **dynamic** so possibly it could be a string or any other data type
so either set the num/double/int to "expectedRevenue" or parse it with double/int/number.

And then for set it to the Text Widget wrap it with () (Brackets) and set .toString() or toStringAsFixed(2) for setting only two digits after the number

**Try This:**

**double expectedRevenue;**

```
Text((e.expectedRevenue*12).toStringAsFixed(2)),
```

or

**dynamic expectedRevenue;**

```
Text((num.parse(e.expectedRevenue.toString())*12).toStringAsFixed(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Understanding the error**

`expectedRevenue` is of type `Dynamic`. So you will get an error when you multiply it by '12' which is an `int`

---

**Solution**

you need to parse it to `int` or `double` as follows -

```
int.parse(e.expectedRevenue);
double.parse(e.expectedRevenue);
```

You can now multiply it by 12 to calculate annual revenue. And then use the `.toString()` method to convert an `int` or `double` to a `String`

Comment: I have used .toString() method